# Unexpected problems with JBoss connection pooling

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jboss, transactions, jta

*I've spend the last days trying to locate the cause of some new problem during development that raised a few days ago... and I've not found it yet. But I've found a workaround. But let's start with the problem itself.*

We are using **JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8)** as our application server for a quite large enterprise project. The JPA layer is handled by **Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final-redhat-1}** using **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (Version 11.2)** connecting **Oracle 11.2.0.3.0**.

A few weeks ago everything worked as expected and we had no database related problems. We were using  the following datasource:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/myDS" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.93:1521:DEV</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>MY_DB</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Most of the time we had 5-10 open connections with 1-3 in use (single development environment)... the pool held that level and worked just fine.

*But with some unknown changes to our code that pool stopped working... didn't release it connections anymore... even did not re-use them at all! It took a few simple requests to fill the pool up to the maximum of 20 connections and JPA refused any new database queries.*

We've spend several days to find the relevant changes to our code... without success!

Today I've discovered a workaround. We changes persistence.xml a little bit:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/myDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"     value="java:/myDSMF" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"                          value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size"         value="1000" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"                  value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode"          value="after_statement" />
   <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode"          value="after_transaction" /> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Changing `hibernate.connection.release_mode` from `after_transaction` to `after_statement` did the trick. But that setting has never been touched before. Now connections are released as expected and the pooling is usable again.

I don't get why after_transaction doesn't work anymore... because changes are committed. We see all these things in the database. And committing a transaction should end it - doesn't it?

Although I've found that simple workaround I'd really get to know the problem. I've no good feeling to delay that knowledge until production time. So any feedback is very well appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have some requests to the database that do not commit or rollback. I'm not 100% sure how sql server handles distributed queries, but it might still open transactions even for distributed select requests and if these are not committed/rolled back  it might explain the scenario you are seeing.

Comment: ...but I've no clue where to look at. This phenomena just appeared one day... the system has been quite complex before and did not have that problem before.

Comment: Did you figure out the cause of this?  I'm having a similar issue

Comment: ...not yet... didn't have any time for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **JTA** . So ***after_transaction*** mode in never recommended for JTA transactions.

Here is the document from JBOSS site.

> **after_transaction** - says to use
> ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION. **This setting should not be
> used in JTA environments**. Also note that with
> ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION, if a session is considered to
> be in auto-commit mode connections will be released as if the release
> mode were AFTER_STATEMENT.

so you should either use **auto** or **after_statement** explicitly, to aggressively release the connection.

#### References

[Connection Release Modes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html).

Comment: FYI a bit off topic but related: JBOSS EAP 6.x always uses `round-robin` datasource connection pools, while 5.x reuse the last-used, and 7.x has configurable policy. This might affect connection pool to Oracle never shrinking back to the `<min-pool-size>`, may be not in your case but in mine.

Comment: (part 2) The section of their DOC regarding DB connection handling was fully removed and it might be inacurate: default value for `<idle-timeout-minutes>` is not mentioned, expected to be 30 min, but it is reported by some users being 0 (disabled). This might lead you to permanent pool filling as well (again not in your case but in mine).

Comment: (part 3) Again off topic, but relevant, missing from the doc:
`prefill=true` will open the min-pool-size at boot (XA & non-XA). `use-strict-min=true` will forcedly open min-pool-size of the XA pool at boot. `no-tx-separate-pools=false` opens only ONE pool, while true opens two (XA and non-XA).